# How to use install package into system directory for SBCL by QuickLisp?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, quicklisp

I'm using quicklisp as the package management tool for SBCL.

However, sometimes I found it's not very convenient to install a package to the HOME directory of current user by `ql:quickload`. (For example, if I use `(ql:quickload "xmls")` to install xmls, other users can't use it.)

What's worse, I'd like to run the lisp code as a script. So when I use the package installed by quicklisp, I need to add the  absolute path of that package uncomfortably, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script
(require 'xmls "..../quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/xmls-1.4/xmls")
```

If I use `(require 'xmls)`, the compiler will not work because it cannot find that package if I use the `--script` options.

Does anyone knows how to solve the problem so that I can use `--script` and `require`(no need to add absolute path) at the same time？

Comment: I'd suggest looking at 'save-lisp-and-die'; just build a new core with all of the packages you need for the scripting, and then use that core when launching sbcl; then there's no need for the requires at the top b/c it's all already loaded in the core. I'm putting this as a comment, b/c it doesn't really answer the question in the title. But it's another approach that I've used when writing lisp scripts; oh, and try #!/usr/bin/env sbcl --script; that's a bit more portable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a good solution to this problem. The solution I use is to not write scripts with Common Lisp; I usually write applications that I use interactively from CL sessions. When I do want to run things from the command-line, I use [buildapp](http://xach.com/lisp/buildapp/) for it, and use `ql:write-asdf-manifest-file` to create a file to pass to `--manifest-file` for buildapp.

I sometimes wish there was a better solution, but it'll probably take some work by someone (hopefully not me).

Answer (score 0):

I just do `sudo sbcl` and this way it'll be installed for every user on my PC - it's OK, because it's my home PC, so there's no danger.

One thing I could think of is maybe symlinking the directory where ql installs stuff to something that is easier to access, like $HOME/packages -> .../quicklisp/software or something?